# How to specify the RTL direction for a column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way in SQL Server that I can specify the RTL direction for a column? Currently I have a query like this:

```
SELECT        IDSource, IDAviculture, Fee , NumberOfReserve, TotalMoney , Name + '(' + Description + ')' AS Descrition, Date 
FROM            dbo.tblReserve
WHERE        (Sell = 1)
```

The data are in Farsi and thus right to left.The problem is unless it is not rtl, it doesn't show the information in correct form.For example the following text needs to be right to left in order for سلام to get inside parentheses:

> علی (سلام)

```
IDSource    IDAviculture   NumberOfReserve TotalMoney  Name + '(' + Description + ')' AS Descrition  Date 
12              5                1500         3000                   علی (توضیحات) 
13              4                 700         2500                   مینا(تست )
```

I expected to be like

```
IDSource    IDAviculture   NumberOfReserve TotalMoney  Name + '(' + Description + ')' AS Descrition  Date 
12              5                1500         3000                  علی (توضیحات) س 
13              4                 700         2500                  مینا (تست ) س
```

Please note that Stack Overflow's editor doesn't support RTL either, so basically it won't show the text correctly. I had to put an extra letter (س) so that it shows it correctly.

Basically what I wrote above can be translated into English as:

```
Name + '(' + Description + ')'

Ali (Description) 
Mina (Test)
```

in English because of being LTR it is fine but when it comes to the RTL content it gets ugly. How can I get this right?

Comment: Might be clearer if you supply example data and only the relevant columns. [Something like this I assume](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10225)

Comment: Can you store the RTL mark (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) with text that should be rendered right-to-left?

Answer (score 0):

Could you store it left to right and then when you select it, use the reverse function, which will effectively display it right to left?

[REVERSE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx)